# Getting multiple checkbox value as non array

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am trying to find a way to get values from multiple checkboxes without naming them as array.
i.e I want to get value for same name for this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name" >
```

Insted of this.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >
<input type="checkbox" name="name[]" >
```

I know this can be done as [CNET](http://www.cnet.com/) is using it.

I think i have to convert this name values into array at server side by something like this.

```
$search= ($_GET['name']);
$array = array();
$array[] = $search;
$a= $arrry;
echo "$a";
```

This certainly is not working.

Can anybody tell me how it can be done.

Thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of your own question from yesterday: [Getting Multiple Checkbox Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11883789/getting-multiple-checkbox-value)

Comment: @Quentin yes may be duplicate, I only asked again as i didn't get any solution for my previous question.

Comment: See [the faq on how to  handle questions that don't get good answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 0):

Certainly its not possible in PHP without having the `[]` in the `name` attribute. But if you want to keep the same name `name` for all the checkboxes then you have to grab the values of selected checkboxes using javascript/[jquery](http://jquery.com/). And then send that comma separated string of values to your php page.

```
   // This is how you will get the values of selected checkboxes
   var csv = '';    
   $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function (i) {
       csv+= this.value + ',';
   });
   alert(csv); // alerts 1,2,3,4,
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/codef0rmer/nssQZ/

Comment: this can work, also When i search in CNET chossing windows and mac their url have this string `&platformSelect=Windows&platformSelect=Mac` which is processed in php(i think). the value `platformSelect` is input name in checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can track the *onSubmit* event.

When it's triggered (for the form hosting the inputs), change the name for each input to something unique (e.g name-1, name-2) or just name[].

What you will get server-side will be easily handled.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to process the QUERY_STRING(or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) instead of accessing $_GET(or $_POST)

Sample(you'll need to refine it, because you can't trust into a proper format of the data-strings):

```
 $__POST=array();
 $__GET=array();
 foreach(array('POST'=>file_get_contents("php://input"),
               'GET'=>$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) as $k=>$v)
 {
   $vv=explode('&',$v);
   foreach($vv as $value)
   { 
    parse_str($value,$var);
    if(!isset(${'__'.$k}[key($var)]))
     {
      ${'__'.$k}[key($var)]=array(reset($var));
     }
     else
     {
      ${'__'.$k}[key($var)][]=reset($var);
     }
   }
 }
print_r(array($__GET,$__POST));
```

Answer (score -1):

not possible.

if you set same name ( which is typically invalid markup TOO )  then only last checked value will be retrieved.

Comment: This is not the case for checkbox and radio type inputs

Answer (score -1):

the $_GET['name'] is array so if use want to reference value in it you can use

```
$_GET['name'][0] // return the first value
```

or if you want to convert it to string

```
$getValue = implode(',',$_GET['name']); // return "value1,value2,value3,value4,value5"
```

Will get the value in **String format**

Comment: this works if i name checkbox like `name="name[]"` not for `name="name"`